# mysql update column self join based on two reference columns (kind of vlookup)

Tags: mysql, self-join

Hope someone can help me out. I have a table `X_Date` with the following data:

```
+----+-----------+------+------+-------+
| ID |   Date1   | Ref1 | Ref2 | Date2 |
+----+-----------+------+------+-------+
| 1  | 22/2/2015 | ABC  | null | null  |
| 2  | 23/4/2015 | DEF  | ABC  | null  |
| 3  | 24/4/2015 | GHI  | null | null  |
+----+-----------+------+------+-------+
```

I would like the query to update the table like:

```
+----+-----------+------+------+-----------+
| ID |   Date1   | Ref1 | Ref2 |   Date2   |
+----+-----------+------+------+-----------+
| 1  | 22/2/2015 | ABC  | null | null      |
| 2  | 23/4/2015 | DEF  | ABC  | 22/2/2015 |
| 3  | 24/4/2015 | GHI  | null | null      |
+----+-----------+------+------+-----------+
```

So the `Date1` of the row where `Ref1` is the same as `Ref2` from a other row needs to be updated as the value of the Date2 column

I have tried some things, however I'm very new to mysql and pretty much know for sure i'm doing this wrong:

```
UPDATE
  `X_Data` AS t1
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT 
    Date1, Ref1, Ref2, Date2 
  FROM 
    `X_Data`
) AS t2
USING (Ref2)
SET
  t1.Date2 = t2.Date1
```

Any help is very much Appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
UPDATE
  `X_Data` t1
INNER JOIN 
  `X_Data` t2
ON t1.Ref2 = t2.Ref1
SET
  t1.Date2 = t2.Date1
```